# $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow \infty}\sqrt[x]{f(x)+x}$ for $|f(x)|<|x|$ and f continuous

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I want to know about $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow \infty}\sqrt[x]{f(x)+x}$ for $|f(x)|<|x|$ and f continuous.
So far I've got a hypothesis. If f(x) doesn't approach $f(x)=-x$, then the limit is 1, if not it is 0. But I still haven't been able to prove it. I found a counter-example for $|f(x)|\leq|x|$ with $f(x)=x*sin(x)$, but I haven't found any for the upper stated conditions. Is my assumption true?

Comment: Assuming you have a clear unwritten definition of "$f(x)$ approaches $-x$ as $x\to\infty$", what about $$f(x)=-x+2^{-x}\quad ?$$

Comment: If I'm correct, your counterexample doesn't quite work since $\lvert f(\epsilon) \rvert \not < \epsilon$ for very small positive $\epsilon$.

Comment: @User8128, but for small positive $\varepsilon$ it doesn't really matter how $f(\varepsilon)$ look likes, so you can just take $f(x) = \frac{1}{2}x$ for small $x$, and connect the two functions in a continuous way such that $|f(x)| < |x|$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: You're absolutely right! Sorry about that.

Comment: Say, $\tilde f(x)=\min\{-x+2^{-x},\, 0\}$

Comment: Moreover, $f(x)=\min\left\{-x+\frac1x, 0\right\}$ satisfies $$\lim_{x\to\infty} \sqrt[x]{f(x)+x}=1$$

Answer (score 1):

We have $0<f(x)+x<2\,x$. Let $\ell=\liminf_{x\to\infty}(f(x)+x)$. If $\ell>0$, then
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\sqrt[x]{f(x)+x}=1.
$$
If $\ell=0$ the limit is indeterminate. For instance, if $a>1$ and $f(x)=-x+a^{-x}$ for $x$ large, then the limit is $1/a$.